# Using Regex to extract file name from URL -- need to exclude some characters

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a resource formatted like the following below:

```
{"url": "http://res1.icourses.cn/share/process17//mp4/2017/3/17/6332c641-28b5-43a0-894c-972bd804f4e1_SD.mp4", "name": "1-课程导学"}, 
{"url": "http://res2.icourses.cn/share/process17//mp4/2017/3/17/a21902b6-8680-4bdf-8f47-4f99d1354475_SD.mp4", "name": "2-计算机网络的定义与分类"}
```

I want to extract the file names `6332c641-28b5-43a0-894c-972bd804f4e1_SD.mp4` and `a21902b6-8680-4bdf-8f47-4f99d1354475_SD.mp4` from the url.

How would I write a regular expression to match the string at this location?

Comment: What is your suggestions?

Comment: @REA what was your solution. Let me know if I can help or clarify

Comment: @TigerTV.ru
@matisetorm

I used `\w.*\.mp4` , output is `url": "http://res1.icourses.cn/share/process17//mp4/2017/3/17/6332c641-28b5-43a0-894c-972bd804f4e1_SD.mp4`.


Beacuse I don't know how to exclude `/` and take the last `/` as a border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `re.findall`:

```
import re
s = [{"url": "http://res1.icourses.cn/share/process17//mp4/2017/3/17/6332c641-28b5-43a0-894c-972bd804f4e1_SD.mp4", "name": "1-课程导学"}, {"url": "http://res2.icourses.cn/share/process17//mp4/2017/3/17/a21902b6-8680-4bdf-8f47-4f99d1354475_SD.mp4", "name": "2-计算机网络的定义与分类"}]
filenames = [re.findall('(?<=/)[\w\-\_]+\.mp4', i['url'])[0] for i in s]
```

Output:

```
['6332c641-28b5-43a0-894c-972bd804f4e1_SD.mp4', 'a21902b6-8680-4bdf-8f47-4f99d1354475_SD.mp4']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a short regex `[^/]*$`

Code:

```
import re
s = [{"url": "http://res1.icourses.cn/share/process17//mp4/2017/3/17/6332c641-28b5-43a0-894c-972bd804f4e1_SD.mp4", "name": "1-课程导学"}, {"url": "http://res2.icourses.cn/share/process17//mp4/2017/3/17/a21902b6-8680-4bdf-8f47-4f99d1354475_SD.mp4", "name": "2-计算机网络的定义与分类"}]
filenames = [re.findall('[^/]*$', i['url'])[0] for i in s]
print(filenames)`
```

Output:

> ['6332c641-28b5-43a0-894c-972bd804f4e1_SD.mp4', 'a21902b6-8680-4bdf-8f47-4f99d1354475_SD.mp4']

Check the regex - https://regex101.com/r/k9VwC6/30

Answer (score 0):

Based on the strings you provided, you could iterate over the dictionaries, get value for "url" and use the following regex

`([^\/]*)$`

Explanation:

```
() - defines capturing group
[^\/] - Match a single character not present after the ^
\/ - matches the character / literally (case sensitive)
* - Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
$ - asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string (if any)
```

For example:

```
for record in records:
    print(re.search("([^\/]*)$", record['url']).group(1))
```

In this case, we are exploiting the fact that the filename occurs at the end of the string. Using the `$` anchor makes the only valid match one that terminates the string.

If you wanted to do this to a dictionary cast as a string, you *could* by changing the ending condition. Like so `([^\/]*?)\",`. Now `",` terminates the match (note the `\` to escape the `"`. See https://regex101.com/r/k9VwC6/25

Finally, if we weren't so lucky that the capturing group was at the end of the string (meaning we couldn't use `$`) we could use a negative look behind. You can read up on those [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: I use `([^\/]*)$`, the output is `a21902b6-8680-4bdf-8f47-4f99d1354475_SD.mp4", "name": "2-计算机网络的定义与分类"}`

Please use [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)(Python) to verify it.

Comment: Then use the second one. you were unclear if you were using it against a string or the dictionary against the string. See https://regex101.com/r/k9VwC6/25 I already solved for that.

Comment: @REA The first on was assuming you were iteration over a dictionary. The second one was assuming you were using the dictionary cast as a string. Both work in their appropriate situations (verified on regex101.com which is where the initial link pointed you). Cheers

Comment: Thanks, I have successfully verified it.